# Web API Validation for Model Bound in GET request

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-binding, url-parameters

I have created a custom Model Binder to read the data from the URI in a specific format

```
public ResponseObject Get([FromUri(BinderType = typeof(CustomModelBinder)]ProductFilter product
{...}

public class ProductFilter
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = @"Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
  public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
  {
      //Code to convert the uri parameters to object
      return true;
  }
}
```

In the above example, i need the name to be passed from the client before executing the Action.
But, I am unable to run the in-built validations on the Product class using this?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote in a custom action filter and I registered this action filter in the GlobalConfiguration for all the services. The action filter hooks on to onActionExecuting, looks for the validation in the bound arguments.

```
        bool isValid;
        foreach (var item in actionContext.ActionArguments)
        {
            var parameterValue = item.Value;

            var innerContext = new ValidationContext(parameterValue);
            if(parameterValue != null)
            {
                var innerContext = new ValidationContext(parameterValue);
                isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(parameterValue, innerContext, results, true);
            }
        }
        //If not valid, throw a HttpResponseException
        if(!isValid)
             throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        else
             base.onActionExecuting(actionContext);
```

With more tuning, the exact validation message can be retrieved from the validation context and sent as the response message.

I was also able to extend this to having validation attributes on the parameters themselves, thereby giving more flexibility to my Api